# Issue with apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I am trying to do forward all incoming requests to https, except if the url contains /axis2 (http://locatlhost/axis2) in URL. This is what I have written (in my `httpd.conf file`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/axis2$ [NC]
RewriteRule $ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

This is not working and I am unable to debug why. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Have you tried removing the starting slash `/` from `^/axis2$` so it looks like `^axis2$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you set up a separate `VirtualHost` for port `443`?**

if yes try removing the `__default__` from the `VirtualHost` directive in your `ssl.conf` / `VirtualHost` directive set by `ssl`.

Which should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

---

First of all I would suggest you to add this in your `VirtualHost`. To log the activities or `mod_rewrite`. It Will be helpful for debugging and higher the `RewriteLogLevel` better for debugging.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/path/to/your/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

From [RewriteLogLevel <sup>Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel):

> To disable the logging of rewriting actions simply set Level to 0. This disables all rewrite action logs.
>   Using a high value for Level will slow down your Apache server dramatically! Use the rewriting logfile at a Level greater than 2 only for debugging!

---

Try this for your issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?axis2/(?:.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/?axis2/)(.*)$ https://$1$2$3 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA,R=301]
```

If the `%{REQUEST_URI}` does not start and end with `/axis2` or `axis2/` or`/axis2/` or `axis2` it will redirect your URIs to `https` and stop any further rule rewriting.

Else, only this will execute:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301]
```

R=301  means a permanent redirection. If just R is specified, a temporary redirect i.e. 302 will be done.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However this is not working, and the URL to be excluded will be of kind http://localhost://axis2/connector. Even if I am trying to hit a URL of kind http://localhost/axis2/ it runs into infinite loop. What might be the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by infinite loop? the page does not load?

Comment: yes, the logs are like:init rewrite engine with requested uri /axis2/
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/axis2/'
RewriteCond: input='/axis2/' pattern='!^/?axis2/?$' [NC] => not-matched
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/axis2/'
rewrite '/axis2/' -> 'http://localhost/axis2/'
explicitly forcing redirect with http://localhost/axis2/
escaping http://localhost/axis2/ for redirect
redirect to http://localhost/axis2/ [REDIRECT/301]
init rewrite engine with requested uri /axis2/
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/axis2/'
RewriteCond: input='/axis2/' pattern='!^/?axis2/?$' [NC] =>not m

Comment: this goes in loop and then my firefox detects that this redirection won't work and stops.

Comment: try the above modified code. If you have specified a log for ssl usually, `logs/ssl_error_log` check what does it say.

Comment: :(, no this doesn't work as well. even the http url without /axis (like http://localhost/abc) is not getting redirecting to https, for URL with /axis the same redirect issue is there. (There was some issue in the rewrite rule that you wrote, it should have been %{QUERY_STRING}, I tried after correcting that as well :( ).

Comment: It worked fine, My bad, I was using mod_jk's JkMount as well, and JkMount for /axis was getting load after this redirect :(. It is working fine now.

Comment: @ankit Good to know it worked :). Oh hadn't noticed that I had missed the `%` before `{QUERY_STRING}`. Have edited the answer to reflect.